# How to compare two array object but any one of the array object does not having key pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

Compare two objects if any one of the object not having key pair.

```
    var itemA= [{"name": "saran", "address":"chennai"},
                       {"name": "elango", "address":"chennai"},
                       {"name": "kala", "address": "chennai"}];

    var itemB= [{"name": "saran", "address":"chennai"},
                       {"name": "elango", "address":"chennai"}];
```

I wrote following code to compare two objects,

```
  function compareJSON(itemA, itemB) {        
      for(var prop in itemA) {
          if(itemB.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
              switch(typeof(itemA[prop])) {
                 case "object":
                    compareJSON(itemA[prop], itemB[prop]);
                       break;
                         default:
                             if(itemA[prop] !== itemB[prop]) {
                             }
                         break;
                }
          }
     }
```

}

Here i have two object i need to compare above two object. I used to for loop for compare two object with hasOwnProperty() method. the prop is having itemA of object it's checked with itemB object if it's different i took itemA object.

Here problem is not able compare itemA 3rd value not able to compare because in itemB does not have a 3rd element.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? Find out if they are equal?

Comment: We can't help you with that code if you don't include `compareJSON`.

Comment: Note that (as the syntax highlighting is telling you), the first code block has a syntax error. (It may be as simple as a missing `"` after `name` on the third line.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: If any of the object comes difference, I need to picked out that object and i have to bold that object in my project

Comment: I have added compareJSON

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

If not equal, you can write your custom modifications/logic.

```js
var itemA= [{"name": "saran", "address":"chennai"},
                       {"name": "elango", "address":"chennai"},
                       {"name": "kala", "address": "chennai"}];

var itemB= [{"name": "saran", "address":"chennai"},
                       {"name": "elango", "address":"chennai"}]; 

let keysA = Object.keys(itemA);
let keysB = Object.keys(itemB);

if(keysA.length === keysB.length) {
 let flag = true;
 keysA.map( a => {
  if(!keysB.includes(a)) {
   flag = false;
  }
  })
  
  flag ? alert('Equal') : alert('Not equal');
} else {
 alert('Not equal');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) can be combined to find the differences between `Arrays` `A` and `B`.

```js
// A.
const A = [
  {name: "saran", address:"chennai"},
  {name: "elango", address:"chennai"},
  {name: "kala", address: "chennai"}
 ]

// B.
const B = [
  {name: "saran", address:"chennai"},
  {name: "elango", address:"chennai"}
]

// Differences.
const differences = A.reduce((differences, object) => (!JSON.stringify(B).includes(JSON.stringify(object)) && [...differences, object] || differences), [])

// Log.
console.log(differences)
```